# Whats the quickest way to append or edit a function in an object?

Tags: javascript

I have an example object like such:

```
var shooter = {fire : function(){shootRightHandGun("shotgun");}}
```

However say the shooter finds a new gun and we want to set shooters fire function to this:

```
{fire : function(){shootRightHandGun("shotgun"); shootLeftHandGun("handgun");}}
```

What would be the best/quickest way to achieve this? Helper functions, a function array in the object, anything. I'm totally open to suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically you can edit functions by getting the function's source code via the `.toString()` method then do string manipulations on it using regexp etc. But it would be very, very messy and I don't recommend it.

Instead, give the object a bit more structure. First separate out right and left hand weapons:

```
var shooter = {
    rightHand : function () {},
    leftHand : function () {},
    fire : function () {}
}
```

Now make the `.fire()` method shoot (or use) all weapons:

```
var shooter = {
    rightHandWeapon : function () {},
    leftHandWeapon : function () {},
    fire : function () {
        this.rightHandWeapon();
        this.leftHandWeapon();
    }
}
```

Now, the code above does nothing (since both functions do nothing) which means that the code above is for an unarmed shooter.

Now you can implement weapons as functions:

```
function shotgun () {
    /* code to fire shotgun */
}

function handgun () {
    /* code to fire handgun */
}
```

To be complete we can define the following function as well:

```
function unarmed () {};
```

Now you can arm the shooter by giving him the weapons:

```
// Armed with shotgun
shooter.rightHandWeapon = shotgun;
shooter.fire();

// Armed with shotgun and handgun:
shooter.rightHandWeapon = shotgun;
shooter.leftHandWeapon = handgun;
shooter.fire();

// Armed with TWO shotguns:
shooter.rightHandWeapon = shotgun;
shooter.leftHandWeapon = shotgun;
shooter.fire();

// Disarm the shooter:
shooter.rightHandWeapon = unarmed;
shooter.leftHandWeapon = unarmed;
shooter.fire(); // does nothing
```

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be replacing functions for that, instead keep track of the items separately, it will probably help you in a long run.
You might need to reference the current items being held by the shooter in a different place in code, do various checks and validations.
Don't just replace functions like this.

```
var shooter = {
    leftGun: null,
    rightGun: "shotgun",

    fire: function() {
        if(this.rightGun != null) {
            shootRightHandGun(this.rightGun);
        }
        if(this.leftGun != null) {
            shootLeftHandGun(this.leftGun);
        }
    }
}

shooter.leftGun = "handgun";
```

You can later easily extend the code with proper setters and getters, easily add some additional checks and so:

```
getRightGun: function() { return this.rightGun; }
setRightGun: function(newRightGun) {
    if(isProperGun(newRightGun)) {              // some kind of a check
        this.rightGun = newRightGun;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To append

```
var temp = shooter.fire;
shooter.fire = (function(t){
    return function(){
    t();
    shootLeftHandGun("handgun");
  }
})(temp);
```

To edit

```
shooter.fire = function(){shootLeftHandGun("handgun");};
```

**Fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/trex005/4rhq7zxj/

Answer (score 1):

If user can find better gun, a good way to do this is to use inheritance for `Gun` class.

Example in es6, but you can easily do this in a es5 using prototypes:

```
class SimpleGun {

    fire: function() {
       shootLeftHandGun("handgun");
    }
}


class BetterGun extends SimpleGun {
    fire: function() {
        super.fire();
        shootRightHandGun("handgun");
    }
}
```

so, when user find another gun, just do something like this:

```
user.setGun(new BetterGun())
```

Comment: I don't think Jason wants to bundle both guns together like this, but otherwise it seems like a good idea too.

Comment: I agree, it depends what exact Jason want to achieve (there are not enough information about all other entities) and also it depends on size of application. If it's going to be big, it's better to think about architecture, but if it's just small app, you probably don't need classes and other stuff.

Comment: To clarify. I want options, and your answer provides that.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your object is not a function constructor and is just a simple object like this, you can simply add whatever you want (properties, methods) to it directly:

```
shooter.shootLeftHandGun  = fucntion() {// Your code here. }
```

But if your shooter has been created from a function constructor (which is not in your case), You can do this easily through your object's prototype.

```
shooter.prototype.shootLeftHandGun = function() {// Your code here.}
```

instead of simply create your object on the fly, try using this:]

```
function shooter() {
   this.shootRightHandGun = function() {
       // Code
   }
   this.name = "default name"
}

var newShooter = new shooter();
newShooter.prototype.shootLeftHandGun = function() { // Your new stuff.}
```

Comment: But,But,But, If your shootLeftHandGun will be something reusable (can be taken by other objects as well, I prefer to create a helper object holding all different types of guns!) This way you can inject proper function into your shooter object when they achieve a new gun. Interesting question anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

This is one more alternative:

```
var shooter = {
    guns:[{side:'right',type:'shootgun'}],
    fire : function(){
        for(var i = 0; i < this.guns.length; i++){
          this.shoot(this.guns[i]);
        }
    },
    gainGun : function(side, type){
        this.guns.push({side:side, type:type})
    },
    shoot:function(gun){
        console.log(gun)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like everyone is piling on here, which is cool. Here's my attempt. If a gun is already equipped in a hand, then that hand is occupied and the user is told about it. I also added a `fireAllGuns` function for the fun of it.

```
var shooter = {
  guns: {},
  fire: function(hand) {
    if (this.guns[hand]) {
      console.log("Firing " + this.guns[hand] + " from " + hand + " hand!");
    } else {
      console.log("There is no gun in that hand!")
    }
  },
  fireAllGuns: function() {
    for (var key in this.guns) {
      if (this.guns.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log("Firing " + this.guns[key] + " from " + key + " hand!");    
      }
    }
  },
  equipGun: function(hand, gun_name) {
    if (!this.guns[hand]) {
      this.guns[hand] = gun_name;
      console.log("Equipped " + gun_name + " in " + hand + " hand");
    } else {
      console.log("That hand is already occupied!")
    }
  }
};

shooter.fire("left");
// There is no gun in that hand!

shooter.equipGun("left", "pistol");
// Equipped pistol in left hand

shooter.fire("left");
// Firing pistol from left hand!

shooter.fire("right");
// There is no gun in that hand!

shooter.equipGun("right", "bazooka");
// Equipped bazooka in right hand 

shooter.fire("right");
// Firing bazooka from right hand!

shooter.fireAllGuns();
// Firing pistol from left hand!
// Firing bazooka from right hand!
```

Comment: What does this line do? `for (var key in this.guns)`.

Comment: I'm iterating through a `for/in` loop. The key is the hand and the value is the gun name. Check out the assignment in the `equipGun` function: `this.guns[hand] = gun_name;`